# SQL Join Across Multiple Tables for Most Recent Date

Tags: postgresql

I know similar Qs have been answered before here, but I'm unable to get the desired output based on answers I've reviewd.

I am trying to join two tables:

[image]

[image]

The objective is to join only records in Table A with the most recent date (A.last_run_date) for a given combination of dp_id AND pm_id, with records from Table B.

Desired Output

[image]

Here's what I came up with, but this is unfortunately not working. The query is returning all the rows, instead of the most recent date (A.last_run_date) for a given combination of dp_id AND pm_id:

```
SELECT b.a_i_id,
       b.a_e_id,
       a.last_run_date,
       a.cm_id,
       a.dp_id
FROM   (SELECT dp_id,
               cm_id,
               Max (last_run_date) AS latest_run
        FROM   a
        GROUP  BY dp_id,
                  cm_id) A1
       INNER JOIN a
               ON a.dp_id = A1.dp_id
                  AND a.cm_id = A1.cm_id
       INNER JOIN b
               ON b.dp_id = a.dp_id
                  AND b.cm_id = a.dp_id
WHERE  Cast (a.last_run_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2023-04-28' AND '2023-04-30'
```

Can someone please advise what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your friend to get a *most recent* row is the analytic function [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-window.html).

Define the `partition by` with the columns that you will be joining and the `order by` on the column defining the order using `DESC`, so that the candidate (highest) row will get the number 1.

Finally filter only row with `rn = 1`. The join is than a trivial case (leaving it out)

```
select 
  last_run_date, dp_id, pm_id,
  row_number() over (partition by dp_id, pm_id order by last_run_date desc) rn
from t;

last_run_date|dp_id|pm_id|rn|
-------------+-----+-----+--+
   2023-04-24|   24| 1000| 1|
   2023-04-23|   24| 1000| 2|
   2023-04-26|   24| 1005| 1|
   2023-04-25|   24| 1005| 2|
   2023-04-27|   25| 1023| 1|
   2023-04-28|   25| 1024| 1|
   
with t2 as (
select 
  last_run_date, dp_id, pm_id,
  row_number() over (partition by dp_id, pm_id order by last_run_date desc) rn
from t
)
select 
  last_run_date, dp_id, pm_id
from t2
where rn = 1;

last_run_date|dp_id|pm_id|
-------------+-----+-----+
   2023-04-24|   24| 1000|
   2023-04-26|   24| 1005|
   2023-04-27|   25| 1023|
   2023-04-28|   25| 1024|
```

**Note** you should always check in this aproach that the columns from `partition by` *and* `order by` are **unique** in the table (i.e. the *last* row is defined stable). Otherwise the query will work, but you can get in each execution a *different* result.

Comment: Thanks @Marmite appreciate it! Your suggestion is working for the most part - however, it seems to be missing a significant number of combinations of dp_id + pm_id. In other words, in the actual database, I see there are many combinations of dp_id + pm_id that satisfy all conditions of the query but are not showing up in the result. There are no obvious differences in the data between the records that are getting returned by the query and those that are getting missed. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: So in other words @DDS are you saying that there is a *combination of dp_id + pm_id* that in my first query is returned only with the `rn` two or higher (and **not** with `rn = 1` and therefore disapears in the seconds query)? This is somehow in a contradiction with the definition of  the `row_number` that starts with `1`, so please recheck your data.

Comment: Thanks @Marmite - I dug further & realized there was an issue with an additional filter that I was adding. Once I fixed that, I'm getting all eligible records. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I just wrote the query out of mind and not tested. You may need to tweak it, but I hope you get the idea.

```
WITH A1 AS (SELECT MAX(last_run_date) max_last_run_date, 
    cm_id, dp_id
    GROUP BY cm_id, dp_id
    )
SELECT b.a_i_id, b.a_e_id, a1.last_run_date, a1.cm_id, a1.dp_id
    FROM B 
    INNER JOIN A1 
    ON B.dp_id = A1.dp_id AND B.cm_id = A.dp_id
```